# How to automatically translate pure code into code that uses mutable arrays for efficiency?

Tags: arrays, optimization, haskell, code-generation, mutable

This is a Haskell question, but I'd also be interested in answers about other languages. Is there a way to automatically translate purely functional code, written to process either lists or immutable arrays without doing any destructive updates, into code that uses mutable arrays for efficiency?

In Haskell the generated code would either run in the `ST` monad (in which case it would all be wrapped in `runST` or `runSTArray`) or in the `IO` monad, I assume.

I'm most interested in general solutions which work for any element type.

I thought I've seen this before, but I can't remember where. If it doesn't already exist, I'd be interested in creating it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  If you have a specific domain in mind then you could create an embedded DSL that builds actions in the ST monad, which might be what you are asking for.  You might also have a look at Data Parallel Haskell, which sounds very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Mutable arrays are usually *slower* than their immutable counterparts. That's because the garbage collector has to treat them specially. So you don't gain anything from using mutable arrays in Haskell.

Comment: @FUZxxl That sounds like an overgeneralisation! What if all my code does is a huge number of mutations on a single large array, and the code is performing too slowly so I want to have it rewritten to use a mutable array instead?

Comment: @FUZxxl References? Or can anybody else confirm this? I find it sceptical. How would a haskeller implement `randomReorder :: Gen gen => gen -> [a] -> [a]` in O(n)? Surely one must use destructive updates here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a functional language using destructive updates is a memory management optimization.  If an old value will no longer be used, it is safe to reuse the old memory to hold a new values.  Detecting that a value will not be used anymore is a difficult problem, which is why reuse is still managed manually.

[Linear type inference](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/linear-logic.html) and uniqueness type inference discover some useful information.  These analyses discover variables that hold the only reference to some object.  After the last use of that variable, either the object is transferred somewhere else, or the object can be reused to hold a new value.

Several languages, including [Sisal](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.43.5160&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [SAC](http://www.sac-home.org/publications/mm-dipl-troj.pdf), attempt to reuse old array memory to hold new arrays.  In SAC, programs are first converted to use explicit memory management (specifically, reference counting) and then the memory management code is optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You say "either lists or immutable arrays", but those are actually two very different things, and in many cases algorithms naturally suited to lists would be no faster (and possibly slower) when used with mutable arrays.

For instance, consider an algorithm consisting of three parts: Constructing a list from some input, transforming the list by combining adjacent elements, then filtering the list by some criterion. A naive approach of fully generating a new list at each step would indeed be inefficient; a mutable array updated in place at each step would be an improvement. But better still is to observe that only a limited number of elements are needed simultaneously and that the linear nature of the algorithm matches the linear structure of a list, which means that all three steps can be merged together and the intermediate lists eliminated entirely. If the initial input used to construct the list and the filtered result are significantly smaller than the intermediate list, you'll save a lot of overhead by avoiding extra allocation, instead of filling a mutable array with elements that are just going to be filtered out later anyway.

Mutable arrays are most likely to be useful when making a lot of piecemeal, random-access updates to an array, with no obvious linear structure. When using Haskell's immutable arrays, in many cases this can be expressed using the `accum` function in `Data.Array`, which I believe is already implemented using `ST`.

In short, a lot of the simple cases either have better optimizations available or are already handled.

Edit: I notice this answer was downvoted without comment and I'm curious why. Feedback is appreciated, I'd like to know if I said something dumb.

Comment: `accum` is implemented using `ST`, at least for some element types, but that doesn't mean it can blindly destructively update arrays passed to it - that would require linear type inference or similar, as described in Heatsink's answer.

Comment: @Robin Green: Right, because there's really two separate problems here--destructive updates when operating on pieces of a larger structure, and identifying when the only use of a reference is as an argument to a function that could operate in place, rather than leaving the old reference for the GC to find. The latter is what Heatsink is talking about, and it's not limited to just arrays.